# Spark Mongodb Connector Unit Tests

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to set up the Spark-MongoDB connector in my test framework. My StreamingContext is set up like this:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
          .setMaster("local[*]")
          .setAppName("test")
          .set("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb.testread")
          .set("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb.testwrite")
```

`lazy val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))`

Whenever I try to set up a DStream like this:

`val records = new ConstantInputDStream(ssc, ssc.sparkContext.makeRDD(seq))`

I get hit with this error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.

It looks like the context is starting and then stopping immediately, but I can't figure out why. The log doesn't give any errors. This is where it finishes starting and then immediately stops:

> DEBUG] 2016-10-06 18:29:51,625 org.spark_project.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle setStarted - STARTED @4858ms o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@33b85bc{/metrics/json,null,AVAILABLE}
>   [WARN] 2016-10-06 18:29:51,660 org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext logWarning - StreamingContext has not been started yet
>   [DEBUG] 2016-10-06 18:29:51,662 org.spark_project.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle setStopping - stopping org.spark_project.jetty.server.Server@2139a5fc
>   [DEBUG] 2016-10-06 18:29:51,664 org.spark_project.jetty.server.Server doStop - Graceful shutdown org.spark_project.jetty.server.Server@2139a5fc by

When I remove the mongodb connection setting it does not shut down and everything is fine (except I can't read/write to mongo :( )

EDIT:
This is the test where I try to write to mongo. However, my test suite fails even before I get to this point.

```
"read from kafka queue" in new SparkScope{

  val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
    ssc,
    PreferConsistent,
    Subscribe[String, String](List("topic"),
      Map[String, Object](
        "bootstrap.servers"->s"localhost:${kServer.kafkaPort}",
        "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
        "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
        "group.id" -> "testing",
        "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
        "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
      )
    )
  )
  val writeConfig = WriteConfig(Map(
    "collection"->"testcollection",
    "writeConcern.w"->"majority",
    "db"->"testdb"
  ), Some(WriteConfig(ssc.sparkContext)))

  stream.map(r => (r.key.toLong, r.value.toLong))
    .reduceByKey(_+_)
    .map{case (k,v) => {
      val d = new Document()
      d.put("key", k)
      d.put("value", v)
      d
    }}
    .foreachRDD(rdd => rdd.saveToMongoDB(writeConfig))

  ssc.start
  (1 until 10).foreach(x => producer.send(KafkaProducerRecord("topic", "1", "1")))
  ssc.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(1500)
  ok
}
```

The failure occurs here when I try to create a stream from a scala collection:

```
"return a single record with the correct sum" in new SparkScope{
    val stream = new ConstantInputDStream(ssc, ssc.sparkContext.makeRDD(seq))
    val m = HashMap.empty[Long,Long]
    FlattenTimeSeries.flatten(stream).foreachRDD(rdd => m ++= rdd.collect())
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(1500)
    m.size === 1 and m(1) === 20
  }
```

The SparkScope class just creates the StreamingContext that I showed above and calls `ssc.stop()` after the test

Comment: Very strange - in the example you aren't doing anything with Mongo at all - can you expand it?

Answer (score 1):

Got it. The problem was that the `SparkConf` variable was not declared `lazy` but the `StreamingContext` was. I'm not sure why that matters, but it does. Fixed.

Comment: Hi user1748268, i have been trying to save data to MongoDB but still not successfull. Can you please share your simplified form of running project so that i can have a look and continue. Thanks in advance, Cheers :)

Comment: Hi @DynamicRemo. The code I posted above is basically complete and actually works perfectly. The problem that I was running into was specs2 related (my scope was an abstract class instead of a trait). What specific problem are you having? Maybe I can help